# GSON parser skipping Object while looping over json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Json array that I parse to GSON. It has the following content:

```
[
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 70215497,
  "nodes": [
    838418570,
    838418571
  ]
},
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 70215500,
  "nodes": [
    838418548,
    838418626
  ]
}
]
```

I tried to parse it using the following sample of code:

```
    while (jsonReader.hasNext()){
                Element type = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Element.class);
                if (type.GetType().contentEquals("way")) {
                    Way way = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Way.class);
                    System.out.println(way.GetId());                
                }
     }
```

Where `Element` is simply

```
public class Element {
    private String type;
    public String GetType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

and `Way` is

```
public class Way {
    private long id;
    private String type;
    List<Long> nodes;       
    public long GetId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Now for some reason only `70215500` will print out. And this happens for a few other elements in the real code. Why is that ?

Edit: It basically only reads 1/2 object. Why?

Comment: it looks you're only printing out the id. "System.out.println(way.GetId());"

Comment: I am. My question is why would it skip the other one

Comment: It's not skipping the other one, you only want to print out the id thats why it's only returning the id.

Comment: well what do you mean ? it should go to the next object of type "way" and print its id as well ?

Comment: Please edit the code sample to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with current and expected output.

Comment: can you check the size of your jsonReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to read `Element` class first and after that `Way` class. Read `Way` and check it's type:

```
try (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(jsonFile))) {
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        Way way = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Way.class);
        if (way.getType().contentEquals("way")) {
            System.out.println(way.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Above code should print all `id`s.

Comment: I will try that. Guess the Element read was consuming my element ...